# PHP - How you cant cheat score in a quiz with previous and forward

Tags: php, html, session

I've searched all over the net but i dont know where to start. 
We need to make a quiz with PHP at school.
If you have a right answer and you go to the next answer you get:

```
session_start(); 

$_SESSION['score']++; 

?>
```

So example, if i made it to question 9 i have 8 points.
But the problem is, if i click on previous it keeps adding ++ to the score. so i have 9 points when im back to question 8. I want to know how to avoid that, and  when you click previous it says "dont cheat".

Comment: just save your nextquestion-number in a session variable, too, and compare it to the actual question.

Answer (score 6):

An easy way to prevent this, is to keep track of the questions a player has already answered. You do this in the same session array, under a different key. Something like this would suffice:

Initialise like this:

```
$_SESSION['answeredQuestions'] = array();
```

Before you add points, you check to see if the question has already been answered:

```
if(!in_array($questionNumber, $_SESSION['answeredQuestions']))
{
    $_SESSION['score']++;
}
```

Then you add the current question to the list of answered questions:

```
$_SESSION['answeredQuestions'][] = $questionNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost as @Sherlock suggested but instead of adding numbers you only need to build this array and add all those numbers together in the end, when you want to show the result (so you don't need to store the score in the session, instead you always store the mapping between question and score that user received for this question).

So every time user answers the question you do something like this:

```
$_SESSION['answers'][$questionNumber] = $scoreForCurrentQuestion;
```

And when you want to get the overall score you will do

```
$score = array_sum($_SESSION['answers']);
```

Comment: Thanks guys, but its still difficult to me, actually its not really about the questions, i just have pages (php's) linked to each other and on each page u visit you'll get ++ score. (if u click the right image (answer)).

Answer (score 0):

I got it!, i did it like this.

```
<?php
session_start(); 

$score = $_SESSION['score']++;

if ($score !=1){
header ('location: index.php');
}

?>
```

So basically, this is the code on page 3, page 3 contains score 1. So if i go from another page (the other page has automatically another score then page 3 because of the session ++), he will redirect to index.php, so not to the previous page.